# Dialog window appear after process is done java

Tags: java, timer, popup, progress-bar, dialog

I have a question, in my app I open the browser with `selenium` library in this way:

```
 WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(): ((HtmlUnitDriver)driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

then I navigate to a specific web page, and the content from that page I store in a `String variable;` Generally it took 5 or 7 seconds to open the page and scan the content and store in my `String variable;`. All I want is to put a dialog box and show the progress, and when the `String variable` is populated the dialog box should to disappear. Here is my code:

```
keyW = txtKeyword.getText();
            search = textField.getText();
            System.out.println("String for car = " + search); 
            System.out.println("String keyword = " + keyW); 



        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        ((HtmlUnitDriver)driver).setJavascriptEnabled(true);

        driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + search);
        tstr1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']")).getText();

        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please wait......");

        //driver.close();
        driver.quit();

        String [] items = keyW.split(","); 
        String [] itemsFromArray = new String[items.length];
        for ( int i = 0; i <  items.length; i++)
        {
            itemsFromArray[i] = items[i].trim();
        }
            for(String string : itemsFromArray)
        {       
            //if (args[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(­ "from:" )) 

            System.out.println("FOREACH " + string);
            int i = countWords(tstr1, string);
            System.out.println("Word count "+ string + ":  " + i);
            Keyword1 = ("Count for word " + string + " are " + i);
            listKeys.add(Keyword1);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a dynamic progress bar you will need to run your processing in a different thread. You can then use the UI thread freely without it being blocked by the processing you are doing. [This](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Creatingamodalprogressdialog.htm) website has s good example of how you can do this. You existing code should replace where the for loop inside the thread. You can use the i value in your for loop to update the progress-bar as it is done in the example.